# Word Formatting Style of Heading in Frame with Border - border/shading goes over margin

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

I am creating a heading style using borders and shading. However both the shading and border go over the page margin. Any clues if this a common problem? I could reduce the spill over the margin using the dialog shown below and setting space from text to 0 - still there remains a tiny bit of spill which I would like to get rid of so it stays within page margins. Only option I found was using the set width shown in the last image - but that screws up the whole position of the heading.

[image: screenshot 1]

Problem Image

[image]

Setting reducing the spill

[image]

[image: Using no boarder - still over margin]

Using Frame width set to Page Width-Margin-Linewidth

Using these specs:

Font: 10 pt, Bold, Font color: Background 1, All caps, Centered
Line spacing:  single, Space
Before:  6 pt
After:  6 pt, Keep with next, Keep lines together, Level 2, Border:
Top: (Single solid line, Auto,  0.5 pt Line width)
Bottom: (Single solid line, Auto,  0.5 pt Line width)
Left: (Single solid line, Auto,  0.5 pt Line width)
Right: (Single solid line, Auto,  0.5 pt Line width)
Pattern: Clear (Text 1), Style: Linked, Hide until used, Show in the Styles gallery, Priority: 10
Based on: Normal
Following style: Normal

Comment: Try without the border

Comment: Edited the post - same problem :(

Comment: OK. I am the one  who upvoted your question because I have a great interest in Frames. This is my web page dealing with them, but it does not address this. http://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#StartPage - can you add a link to a sample document with the problem? That would save anyone trying to help you a lot of time. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258